# Python - ffmpeg-like media seeking with requests

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, streaming, python-requests

Using ffmpeg, times in HTTP media resources, such as videos, can be seeked to very quickly with a command like `ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i https://example.com/video.mp4`, presumably by downloading the video headers to look for the right byte offset. This means that it is very fast to run operations on a section of video, even if it is hours in.

What I want to be able to do is to do the same thing but piping into ffmpeg with the requests module with something like (in partial pseudo-code):

```
stream = requests.get(url, stream=True)
start_byte = get_byte_offset(stream, time=60)
stream.seek_to(start_byte)

process = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i" "pipe:" "out.mp4"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

for chunk in stream.iter_content(chunk_size=64 * 2 ** 10):
    process.stdin.write(chunk)
process.stdin.close()
```

This would allow me to implement extra checks into the stream that I would normally need to parse ffmpeg for, such as if the stream returns a bad status code such as 404 or 403.

How might I be able to implement this using the requests, and presumably other, modules? I suppose the first part is using a tool to parse the video headers.